# MSI wrapper from command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-installer, zabbix

Is there any MSI wrapper that works from a command line? Or even an MSI creator that could be automated?

I have a client that requires an MSI file to roll out into their windows server environment. What I need to package is a .exe file (windows Zabbix agent) that installs itself as a service from wherever the file is located when you run it.

Currently I have a self-extracting .exe that runs a batch file, and then I use a free MSI wrapper to convert it to MSI.

I'm trying to automate this so my co-workers can change zabbix config files and then run a batch that creates the package for them. I can do everything up to creating the MSI.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use http://www.suiviperf.com/zabbix/.

Or check Zabbix forum, it contains similar questions:
e.g. https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=22688

Answer (score 0):

You can try Advanced Installer, it has a free 30 days trial for you to test. The Professional edition can help you [create and MSI that wraps your EXE](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-convert-exe-to-msi.html) (one or many).

Also, it has a [command line interface](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/command-line.html), so you can automate the build process for the setup package.